Clicking `Create` on Custom Safe deployment is not working

I followed these steps in order for reaching this far:

Got the network added and contracts deployed Singleton-Factory and Safe-deployments.
Set up safe-infrastructure locally, got all the services up and running via sh run-locally.sh script.
Added our chain on to the network and manually added all the contract addresses on the page.

I had 2 Questions for this step:
Q.1: what is Safe web authn signer factory address? Is it the address which deployed the Singleton-Factory on our network (which is the same address as all networks)? The last address on the list below

Q.2: What is Recommended master copy version: value supposed to be? Is this the version of safe-smart-account we used to deploy our smart contracts? (I am using 1.4.1 since that's the version I used, or is it something else?)

Added the MasterCopies and ProxyFactory on /tx/admin panel

Question: In Master Copy contracts (Safe and SafeL2 there is a checkbox for L2, does it have to be checked for both Safe and SafeL2, or just SafeL2?) Do I have to add both contracts in Master Copy (Safe and SafeL2?)

Added the web hook on the events admin panel.

After these steps, I start the UI but the Create button doesn't work.
Some things to better navigate the issue:
Logs on safeglobal/safe-client-gateway-nest:latest (not being able to pick up ChainID)
{"build_number":"40b1555","level":"info","message":{"chain_id":null,"client_ip":"192.168.144.1","detail":null,"method":"GET","origin":null,"path":"/v1/owners/0x1dce40e247ABb0B6Ca09940B90541b58581B81D8/safes","response_time_ms":31.79708300018683,"route":"/v1/owners/:ownerAddress/safes","safe_app_user_agent":null,"status_code":200},"request_id":"bc03b671-079f-4752-8055-b7809ee3aadc","timestamp":"2024-08-02T19:31:32.439Z","version":"v1.52.0"}

Another thing I noticed was on /txs/admin panel where we set MasterCopy version, the block number changes when we mark a contract as L2 on every refresh (as seen here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xnf9LNqijaeKoN63m5i4h93W3oPNrrQS/view?usp=sharing), and this same thing was happening for proxy contracts (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w1E355xL7oE6krkXFVuCMlEOYvyJVYzB/view?usp=sharing)
Also, my chain is part of chain list but it's not in the https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/protocol-kit/src/utils/eip-3770/config.ts

Thanks for the detailed question! We'll be looking at it on Monday as the team is off on weekends. Please hang tight in the mean time

Hi @Louis-SafeCoreTeam thanks for getting back, just a reminder for this issue in case it missed the team's attention. I've added 2 videos on some erraneous behaviour of what I'm seeing on my /tx/admins dashboard


Safe web authn signer factory address is specific to passkeys, a list of deployments can be found here.

Recommended master copy version can be either 1.4.1 or 1.3.0, as older versions won't support latest features.

You can select only L2.


Hope it helps, please let me know if you have further questions 
Best; Louis
